# How do I get phone info in QT? (carrier, device model, device manufacturer)

Tags: qt, symbian, s60, qt-mobility

I've found something like below on the net

```
//Get S60 version and display it on label
switch (QSysInfo::s60Version ())
{
    case QSysInfo::SV_S60_3_1: return "S60 version: S60 3.1";
    case QSysInfo::SV_S60_3_2: return "S60 version: S60 3.2";
    case QSysInfo::SV_S60_5_0: return "S60 version: S60 5.0";
    case QSysInfo::SV_S60_Unknown: return "S60 version: S60 Unknown";
    default:
    break;
}

//Get OS version and display it on label
switch (QSysInfo::symbianVersion ())
{
    case QSysInfo::QSysInfo::SV_9_2: return "Symbian OS version: 9.2";
    case QSysInfo::SV_9_3: return "Symbian OS version: 9.3";
    case QSysInfo::SV_9_4: return "Symbian OS version: 9.4";
    case QSysInfo::SV_Unknown: return "Symbian OS version: Unknown";
    default:
    break;
}
```

BUT this doesn't compile as the QSysInfo class doesn't have s60Version method nor the symbian Version - I only get windowsVersion...

Comment: Which version of Qt, on which platform?

Comment: It should have `s60Version()` then. But only when you're compiling for Symbian emulator or device target. The simulator target is plain Windows, for example `Q_OS_SYMBIAN` is not defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, found it - for everybody that needs that stuff:

```
QString carrierName = QSystemNetworkInfo::networkName(QSystemNetworkInfo::GsmMode);

QtMobility::QSystemDeviceInfo* d = new QtMobility::QSystemDeviceInfo(this);
QString imei = d->imei();
QString manufacturer = d->manufacturer();
QString model = d->model();
delete d;

QtMobility::QSystemInfo* s = new QtMobility::QSystemInfo(this);
QString osVer = s->version(QSystemInfo::Os);
delete s;
```

hope this helps someone :)
cheers!