# Find device details (IMEI,MMC,OS info) in QT Windows phone 8.1

Tags: qt, c++11, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, qt5

I have developing a windows phone 8.1 application, Can any help me get the device id for windows phone 8.1 in Qt5.4/C++?

the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125314/how-do-i-get-phone-info-in-qt-carrier-device-model-device-manufacturer) doesn't work!

Does anyone have any idea how to crack this?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not allow you to read IMEI. Here is a way to get the unique device id.

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Info;

byte[] myDeviceID = (byte[])Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceUniqueId");
```

so now you ll have the id. It needs to be converted into proper format.

```
string DeviceID = Convert.ToBase64String(myDeviceID);
```

you can now use the string for your purpose.

Comment: and don forget to check on ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE in the application manifest. Else your application will not have permission to perform this task.